# python - writing geojson to file

Tags: python, geojson

I'm playing around with the Google Maps API and I want to get the PolyLine then convert it to Lat,Lon then to GeoJSON so I can visualise it with Mapbox. I've got most of the way but am stuck on how to write the final GeoJSON to a file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#creates empty list for geoJSON
geoList = []

for i in URLlist:
    polylineData = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(i))


# try ... except will do what you want when true and put exceptions into false
    try:
        # looks up polyline string from JSON
        polylineExcerpt = polylineData['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points']
        # use polyline module to decode into lat,lon
        waypointData = polyline.decode(polylineExcerpt)

        # use geojson library to encode to GeoJSON
        encodeWaypoint = LineString(waypointData)

        # uses swapCoord function to reverse lat lon
        for feature in encodeWaypoint['coordinates']:
           flip = swapCoords(feature)
           appendLine = geoList.append(flip)

        # # puts it back into GeoJSON
         convertToGeoJSON = LineString(geoList)

     except: 
        print('something went wrong')
```

So I have all the JSON elements in a list but am not sure how to write it to a file with proper encoding. If I do something like:

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(convertToGeoJSON, f)
```

Then it doesn't produce a valid JSON, is there a way to create the final JSON better?

Comment: can you print `convertToGeoJSON`

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt produce a valid json"?

Comment: @ZdaR yep it prints each geojson object one by one but I can't work out how to combine them into a file with commas seperating each object and with [ at start and ] at end of file

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon it dumps everything into a file but there are no commas between each object or with [ and ] at start and end of file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of GeoJSONs by appending one GeoJSON at a time to a list in each iteration of the loop. Then finally write the Json array to a file at once.

eg:

```
geo_json_list = []
for i in your_list:
   #code to generate your geoJSON
   geo_json_list.append(geo_json)
with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(geo_json_list, f)
```

When loading it to python you can simply do this

```
json=open('data.json') 
data = json.load(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but i want to elaborate on the answer for future problems people may have. I was trying to use a for loop to create a .geojson file that contained a FeatureCollection with many features. I used the geojson library with a for loop to access data from my database using SQL. I struggle a lot but as a result learned a ton so i want to share what i learned.

A FeatureCollection is like a container for zero or more features (yes you can have no features and its still a valid file) a feature is like an object in the FeatureCollection such as a point, line, polygon, multipoint, etc. Features have geometry and properties, geometry for a point is longitude and latitude. properties can be anything really, they are like attributes.

This is how you create a FeatureCollection with one feature:

```
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection, dump

# Create point - longitude goes first and latitude goes second
point = Point((-115.81, 37.24)))
features = []
features.append(Feature(geometry=point, properties={"country": "Spain"}))
# Add more features

feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection, f)
```

This is how i created a FeatureCollection with over 12,000 features:

```
import sqlite3
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection, dump

conn = sqlite3.connect('usgs_earthquake.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''SELECT Location.location, Location.latitude, Location.longitude, Event.depth, Event.magnitude, Event.time, Status.status, Event.tsunami, Ids.ids FROM Event JOIN Location JOIN Ids JOIN Status ON Event.location_id=Location.id AND   Event.ids_id=Ids.id AND Event.status_id=Status.id''')
features = []
for row in cur:
  loc = row[0]
  lat = row[1]
  lon = row[2]
  dep = row[3]
  mag = row[4]
  tim = row[5]
  sta = row[6]
  tsu = row[7]
  ids = row[8]
  
  point = Point((lon, lat))
  
  features.append(Feature(geometry=point, properties={'location': loc, 'Depth': dep, 'Magnitude': mag, 'Date/Time': tim, 'Status': sta, 'Tsunami': tsu, 'ids': ids} ) )


feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open('usgs_earthquake.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection, f)
# Note you dont need json.dump() if you use the geojson module in python. just use dump().
```

Hope this helps